# "OK, google" with screen off, device charging

Tags: 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g

**Device:** Moto G5 Plus

---

I just got the Moto G5 Plus 3 days ago. 
I remember that during the set-up I marked the option to recognize "Ok, google" with a locked phone when the screen is on and when the screen is off but the phone is being charged.

It recognizes well when the screen is on but I can't make it activate when the screen in off with the phone charging!

I have looked everywhere for an option specifically for this (even though I specifically remember marking this option when I was setting the phone), but couldn't find it anywhere.

I gotta know if this is a bug or something to see if I should get the phone replaced.

Thank you

Comment: This is a bug since 2014, that sometimes gets fixed sometimes not. Not sure about the current status

Comment: @beeshyams but is it a bug from the moto line or from the android system? Does this bug have a "nickname" so that I can google it?

Comment: From Google.  Just [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ok+Google+doesn%27t+work+on+charging&oq=ok+Google+doesn%27t+work+on+charging&aqs=chrome..69i57.15415j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) - this search is filtered for last year. Without the filter you can see it being discussed since 2014

Comment: Pretty sure Google removed this feature so you have to buy a Google Home device